# Read csv asynchronous - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, async-await

I'm looping an array and reading from a CSV file so I can reduce its data, I've implemented something like this. I want to have a Map variable populated from a csv file in memory and get data from it. But I want to populate it once (or when I explicitly do so, but that's other thing).

when running I would like to print like this:

```
before 
after
```

But I'm getting this:

```
before
before
before
after
after
after
```

Apparently when reading from the CSV is not awaiting. Is there any way I can read from CSV asynchronous?

This is my code:

```
let myMap = new Map();
const parseMap = async(stream) => {
    const map = new Map();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream
           .on('data', elems => {
              const key = elems[0];
              const value = elems.slice(-1)[0];
              map.set(key, value);
           })
           .on('error', () => reject)
           .on('end', () => {
             console.log('promise');
             resolve(map);
        });
  });  
}

const getMap = async(path_string) => {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path_string).pipe(parse({delimiter: DELIMITER}));
    return await parseMap(stream);
    
}
const translate = async (key) => {
    if (!myMap.size) {
        console.log('before');
        myMap = await getMap('my-csv.csv');
        console.log('after');
    }
    return myMap.get(key);
};

const guidRankings = await ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce(async (accumulator, value, idx) => {
        const data = await translate(value);
        if (data) {
            (await accumulator).push({
                data,
                order: idx
            });
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, Promise.resolve([]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` method can't handle an ascynrous callback.

You need to pass it a function that returns the actual value you care about, not one that returns a promise.

1. `map` your array values through `translate` to get an array of promises
2. Use `await Promise.all` to wait for them all to settle and get an array of the translated values
3. `reduce` that array (without doing anything asynchronous inside the reducer).

Comment: Yeah, I tried with map, I'm getting the same. The problem is that when reading the csv doesn't await

Comment: What do you want it to wait for? You're translating 3 things so the translate function is going to run 3 times and log before and after three times, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Correct, the translate function is called three times, but it has a if statement that will `getMap`(read from the csv file) only when there's no data in the `myMap` map, so this should happen only in the first iteration

Comment: The `if` has nothing to do with how many times the `console.log` statements fire, and should be resolved if you do what I said and don't try to do anything asynchronous in the reducer.

Comment: const result = await Promise.all(['a', 'b', 'c'].map(async (i,order) => {
  const id = await translate(i);
  return {
   id,
   order
  };
 }));

Comment: I'm getting the same result

Comment: What same result? That `translate` runs three times? Yes! I said that would happen. It has to happen because you pass three sets of data through it.

Comment: I don't get you. I agree the translate function should run 3 times, but there is a `if` that evaluates the size of the map, so the first iteration is 0, but the second iteration is 10 for example, why would it enter the if statement in the second iteration? `myMap` is a global variable

Comment: I don’t know - you haven’t shown your implementation of reduce with my advice applied.

Comment: My comment above shows the Map and Promise.all. The reduce doesn't matter at this point since doesn't call the translate function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 3 calls can be made at same time it just using map to store the promises, using Promise All to wait for them to complete, and then a map to get your array.

```
const promises = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(value) => translate(value));
const results = await Promise.all(promises);
const guidRankings = results.map((data, order) => ({ data, order }));
```

If for some reason they have to be made one at a time you want to use [for await of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)